# How to copy array value to another array

Tags: c, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
char roundNames1[16][25], roundNames2[16 / 2][25];
```

I then want to copy a result from the first array to the second. I have tried this:

where `roundNames1[5] = "hello"`

```
#include <string.h>

printf("First array: %s", roundNames1[5]);
strcpy(roundNames1[5], roundNames2[6]);
printf("Second array: %s", roundNames2[6]);
```

But this just returns

```
First array: hello
Second array:
```

Why is it not working?

Comment: Yes I noticed this but I also did a test with `roundNames2[5]` and it didnt work

Comment: Also, the parameters to `strcpy()` should be reversed!

Comment: @Lundin that is not true

Comment: Oh sorry you didn't reverse the order of the strcpy parameters, just changed the index to something within array bounds. The strcpy reverse bug is indeed still there, then. Previous comment deleted.

Comment: @Lundin haha no worries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exchange arguments of function strcpy

```
strcpy( roundNames2[8], roundNames1[5] );
```

Here is a part pf the function description from the C Standard

**7.23.2.3 The strcpy function**

Synopsis

1

```
#include <string.h>
char *strcpy(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2);
```

Description

> 2 The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including
>   the terminating null character) into the array pointed to by s1. If
>   copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined.

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy` - arguments other way around.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Answer (score 0):

## Copy arrays/strings with `memcpy`

```c
void * memcpy (void * destination, void * source, size_t size)
```

The `memcpy` function copies an certain amount of bytes from a source memory location and writes them to a destinaction location. [(Documentation)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

### Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char some_array[] = "stackoverflow";

    int memory_amount = sizeof(some_array);
    char *pointer = malloc(memory_amount);
    memcpy(pointer, &some_array, memory_amount);

    printf("%s\n", pointer);

    free(pointer);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
$ ./a.out 
stackoverflow
```